# Cannot get casperjs to run in Mac OS

Tags: macos, github, casperjs

Trying to get casperjs installed on Mac OS X 10.9 and not having much luck.

Followed these steps:

```
git clone git://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
cd casperjs git checkout tags/1.0.0-RC2 
sudo ln -sf /home/dev/casperjs/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

Since the PATH already has /usr/local/bin the last command should allow it to work, no?

When I try to run casperjs from the terminal I get the following error:

```
-bash: casperjs: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the path - also is the execute bit of /home/dev/casperjs/bin/casperjs set?

Comment: I'm not sure if this belongs on StackOverflow, because the same problem could have occurred with a program not programming related. Whatever the community decides, I think it's better suited for SuperUser or Unix&Linux.

Comment: Yes, it is set as executable. Even if I go into directory, type casperjs and enter to run it says command not found. Should I post this to SuperUser or Unix&Linux instead?

Comment: Have you installed PhantomJS as well? PhantomJS is the headless browser that Casper uses for loading pages. Make sure you've got the prerequisites installed - http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#prerequisites

Comment: Hey guys, just wanted to update that I used homebrew to install the latest stable version, one of the dependencies is PhantomJS and it takes care of this as part of the install process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can use `brew` like this :

```
brew install casperjs
```

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)